# How do I make a repeating text in an SVG?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to create a text that says "Draft" and repeats indefinitely. It will be used to fill a page with watermarks. (I'm using SVG for this, instead of background-image, because I need it to appear in the print view as well).

Everywhere I look, I see examples of SVGs with repeating shapes. For example, this:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style="border: 1px solid red">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="basicPattern" x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#64bee3" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="2" fill="url(#basicPattern)" />
</svg>
```

But when I try to replace the shape in the pattern with `<text>`, it doesn't work (nothing appears in the svg).

How do I create a text that repeats indefinitely in intervals?

Comment: Did you even try google? https://thenewcode.com/1051/Generate-Page-Watermarks-with-SVG

Comment: Add a `y` attribute to the text. By default y="0"  and alignment-baseline="baseline" will throw the text outside the pattern. Alternatively you may try `alignment-baseline="hanging"`

Comment: @j08691 Yes I did try Google, for multiple hours. I'm not sure why I missed that post, but if you think that it serves Stack Overflow better when people find their answers elsewhere, I can always delete this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it for the text as **@enxaneta** kindly advised: `By default y="0" and alignment-baseline="hanging"`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style="border: 1px solid red">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="basicPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="100" >
            <text x="50" y="0" font-family="Avenir" font-size="40" alignment-baseline="hanging">Draft</text>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#basicPattern)" />
</svg>
```

***The second option with filling the pattern with text at an angle.***

To implement the tilt of a line of text, `patternTransform="rotate(-35)"` has been added

```html
<svg width="100%" height="600" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style="border: 1px solid red">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="basicPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="150" height="100" patternTransform="rotate(-35)" >
            <text x="70" y="0" font-family="Avenir" font-size="30" alignment-baseline="hanging">Draft</text>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
   <rect width="100%" height="650" fill="url(#basicPattern)" />
</svg>
```